# Bootstrap 5 - Card Element Alignment on the Bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Okay so I'm new with Bootstrap, and I'm trying to place one button element to be on the bottom of the Card all the time, even when body text is small. However, I'm always receiving this result, which is not placing my button on the bottom right corner where I need it to be.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/*">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card col-8">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h2 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">John Doe</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle pb-3">Developer</h5>
              <p class="card-text pb-3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <div class="row justify-content-between">
                    <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-primary">Portfolio</a>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/linkedin.svg" alt="Linkedin Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter Icon" width="32" height="32">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the element nested in a `bootstrap row` you can add the class `justify-content-end` which is synonymous with `justify-content: flex-end;` I also declared a width on your `a tag` at `w-25`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/*">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card col-8">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h2 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">John Doe</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle pb-3">Developer</h5>
              <p class="card-text pb-3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-primary w-25">Portfolio</a>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edit ~** "what if I have two elements inside that row, and I want to place one on the right/start and the other on the left/end?"

Then use `justify-content-between`. See below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/*">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card col-8">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h2 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">John Doe</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle pb-3">Developer</h5>
              <p class="card-text pb-3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-primary w-25">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-primary w-25">Portfolio</a>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But what if I have two elements inside that row, and I want to place one on the right/start and the other on the left/end? How to align them?

Comment: @Hassa see edits.

Comment: The second element is div with multiple images/social icons, and it will not work, even when it's parent has justify-content-between

Comment: I will create a new one then, and rate your answer here.